# Finalizing VPN, won't save

Tags: openvpn, certificates

I have followed a guide on wiki-how for setting up an VPN tunnel to ensure somewhat anonymous internet browsing. I have created a virtual PC with Ubuntu on it and bought a VPS service. I have also configured an FTPclient through putty (an SSH client) so that I could install openVPN on my VPS. I have logged on to my openVPN and downloaded the `client.ovpn` and now I am at the final step, I just need to access the VPN via the `client.ovpn`. The guide was some lackluster at places so it has been somewhat of a hassle.

Anyway now there is only one step left and that is creating the actual connection from my virtual PC to the openvpn tunnel. Just one problem, it wont let me save at the last window. It seems like I am lacking in a bunch of certificate, how do I get those? Or is there any other problem I need to fix? Any advice or guides will be appreciated.

The wikihow guide (I have followed the steps in 'Browsing with Strong Anonymity*): 
http://www.wikihow.com/Be-Online-Anonymously

A screen dump of the problem at hand:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See all the file selection panels that read (None)? I think you need to set the client user credentials before you can finalize the VPN connection configuration.

Comment: Thanks and I think you are right, I just have no idea where I get all those certificates. If it is something that are created by me, or I have to download from my openVPN.

Comment: I don't know either but so far this is outside of the scope of your question. You can amend it if you want or open a new question.